# What can I do if last year's crocuses did not bloom?

Tags: overwintering, bulbs, rain

[image]Last year (2023) I bought some crocus bulbs and planted them a little late in January or February of 2023. Surprisingly, they did bloom and went through their cycle. I let the foliage die off naturally and did not trim. I left them in their pots outside over the summer and winter months. I live in a very wet and raining area, I often get moss and litcheon growing in my pots and along the side of the house. This year (Jan 2024) the crocuses sprouted some foliage but they did not bloom. Is there anything I can do to help them this year or is it better to start fesh in the autumn?

I live in Zone 9, UK/Ireland.

Comment: What hardiness zone do you live in?

Comment: Zone 9, UK/Ireland

Answer (score 5):

Given that you're in zone 9, you're too warm for crocuses to successfully bloom; they're rated no warmer than US zone 8. You could get them to bloom by giving them a cold treatment for the winter. This is usually done in warm areas by putting their pot in a refrigerator for the winter. You could also treat them as annuals, buying the corms, refrigerating them for two or three months, and then planting them.

Comment: Crocus do pretty well in southern England, and can establish themselves nicely (but not in my garden; I blame the months of soggy clay every year)

Answer (score 2):

Nothing you can do yourself, as you left the greens to ripen last year properly. Leaves without bloom mean the plants are **not going to rebloom further**. *I've had 12 tulip bulbs bloom 12 in Spring 1, 3 in Spring 2, and 1 the next.*

Follow the wisdom in the Jurp answer.

Isn't Irish soil acid (peat moss)? Asia Minor bulbs are not fans! Maybe in pots with cactus potting mix?